# How to get Advanced Custom Field Value According using POST ID?

Tags: posts, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I have used [**`Advancedcustomfields`**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin to create Advanced Custom Fields.

***Now, want to get an Advanced Custom field value using post id.***

I have tried below and get solution.

***Now,please let me know if any other way I will get same result?***

```
  <?php

    $post->ID='15';

    $var_name= get_field('field_name', $post->ID);
    /* field name means which u gave custom field name*/
    echo $var_name;

    ?>
```

Comment: what do you want to change in your solution ?

Answer (score 2):

The solution you used seems correct. But if you still want to know alternatives, here it is:

```
$varname = get_post_meta($post_id, 'fieldname', true);
echo $varname;
```

`$varname` will be an array if the last parameter is `false` and will be the value of metadata field if the last parameter is `true`.

You can use `the_field()` as well which works similar to `get_field()` you used.

Comment: > _The last parameter returns the format of the field value_ Parameter returns? What???

Comment: @max I means the function returns array of last parameter is false and value of meta field if it's true. Grammar mistake sorry!